# Get a field from a string, store it in a variable, and compare it

Tags: tcl

I have

```
From: "1234"<sip:1234@8.43.33.101;x-j1;x-refci=27684157;x-just1=S58>;tag=4834BAF1
```

I want to copy `x-j1;x-refci=27684157;x-just1=S58` from above `From` header and store it in a variable say `s1` and compare with `s2` (which is another variable containing a similar string).

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: no jerry. I am very new to tclktk.

Comment: I just need to check this for one case that's it

Comment: This will be helpful for you: Tcl documentation is at https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm -- read through the [Tcl man page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm), it describes the syntax rules for the language (only 12 rules)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression: capture the text between the first semi-colon and the end angle bracket:

```
set str {From: "1234"<sip:1234@8.43.33.101;x-j1;x-refci=27684157;x-just1=S58>;tag=4834BAF1}
regexp -- {.*?;(.+)>} $str all wanted
puts $wanted ; # => x-j1;x-refci=27684157;x-just1=S58
```

or use find the relevant substring

```
set start [string first {;} $str]
set end [string first {>} $str]
set wanted [string range $str $start+1 $end-1]
```

Comment: Any special reason not to use `regexp {.*?;(.+)>} $str all wanted`?

Comment: No, I just prefer inline

Comment: A note to readers: You often see `regexp` called like this: `regexp $pattern $string -> capture_var` -- with the odd symbol `->`. That's a common idiom to indicate to the reader that we don't care about the whole text that matched, we only care about the captured part. `->` is actually a valid Tcl variable name. I could have used `->` in my answer instead of `all`.